# How to handle state across different reducers for triggering notification in react redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How do i update root state on store from one reducer to another reducer if some message notification triggers. I want to change message state of store when user login happens and wants to show that message on top level MESSAGE component. I want to change message state from userReducer on dispatching LOGIN_FAILURE action. But it is updating message in initialState.user.messages itself but i want to update in initialState.messages not in initialState.user.messages.

**How can i do this ?**

**Dispatching LOGIN_FAILURE actions.**

initialState.js

[image]

rootReducer.js used in createStore

[image]

userReducer.js

[image]

messageReducer.js

[image]

App.js in which MESSAGE component is used

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you may know each reducer has its own state, so for example for `userReducer` you are using the `initialState`, so

```
const initialState = {
  user: {},
  messages: []
};
```

the initial state above , it's used into userReducer only, so it is namespace for user only instead of be sharing cross reducer, so whatever change you do into `userReducer` will affect only its state I mean `user: {}`, in the case that you want to update `messages` for `messageReducer`, so should move your logic for `LOGIN_FAILURE` to the reducer that is intended to affect, so if for example yo need to listen for `LOGIN_FAILURE` into `userReducer` too, you can do it, but this should be done only if you need to affect something related to the user state instead of message state.